# Is it possible to make a regular grammar enforcing usage of a given character?

Tags: grammar, regular-language

*Disclaimer: I'm a total newbie in a given topic, so my apologies in advance if I formulated the question not clearly or ambiguously.*

Let's consider the grammar `G = (N, T, P, S)` with character A ∈ T.

Is it possible to build such set of rules `P` that any string generated by `G` contains exactly one character `A` at any position? Can you give an example of that grammar? `G` should be able to generate multiple multicharacter strings from `N`.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I won't give you the solution but a pointer. Try breaking the problem up. Make a rule to generate a string that ends with the desired character and a rule to add a suffix to any string. Btw, N is usually used for the set of NON-terminals. I think your A is meant to be a terminal, no?

Comment: I'm not sure about `A`. Why do you think it must be a terminal?

Comment: Because a *language* doesn't know about non-terminals at all. It is a sub-set of the Kleen closure of the terminal alphabet. The non-terminals are just a means to define the grammar. There are other ways to define a language as well. (Since your language is regular, defining it via a regular expression would be an alternative, for example.) And the sentence "any string generated by G contains exactly one character A at any position" doesn't make much sense if A is not a terminal symbol. The grammar will never "generate strings" with non-terminals. Those are just intermediary.

Comment: Ah, now I see..